# keep a div outside of a canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to be able to keep a draggable div from moving into a canvas. I don't want the div to be dragged in the canvas at all. I have tried a div as the deflecting element, but it is really complicated and it glitches. How do I achieve this?

Code:

## HTML:

```
<div id="drag"></div>
<canvas></canvas>
```

## CSS:

```
#drag {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: khaki;
}
canvas {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: aqua;
}
```

## jQuery:

```
$("#drag").draggable();
```

Comment: `keep an element outside of another element?` **&&** `The draggable div will be able to pass into the other element` I'm really not sure to understand your expected behaviour

Comment: I will fix the error.

Comment: I tried to fix it.

Comment: Maybe this can help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781346/keep-a-draggable-div-inside-its-parent